# How do I fix Rails RuntimeError Current ExectJ doesn't support ES5?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, node.js, ruby, rubygems

When I go to update the page "localhost: 3000" at the end of the lesson I get what happens in the image I have attached. While if I unload "node.js" the "localhost: 3000" does not work anymore, i.e. it gives me this error "We're sorry, but something went wrong.If you are the application owner check the logs for more information." Why?

[image: RuntimeError image]

Comment: What do you mean by "unload node.js" ?  Have you actually installed node.js in your system?  What do you get in your terminal if you type `node -v` ?

Comment: Yes, I installed Node.js on my pc. When I use node -v it goes out:

$ node -v
v11.1.0

Comment: Help me @lacostenycoder

Comment: First try to run `gem install execjs` 
Include your `Gemfile` code and add the following outputs to your question. From terminal type `gem env`.  I assume you ran `bundle install`?  Also see https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme.  

Are you able to show all of your project code say on Github repo?

Comment: @lacostenycoder

This is my project on Github (https://github.com/NeoXinco/LacerMarket).

This is the image of the termial (https://imgur.com/a/OsC2utd),

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem was in your Gemfile here

```
gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby
gem 'mini_racer', platforms: :ruby
```

You had two racer type gems, you only need one.

You should just use `gem 'mini_racer'` and get rid of `therubyracer`. Do that and run `bundle install`. You will also need to clean up merge conflict stuff left in your `routes.rb` file. Do that before `bundle install` and you should be good.

You probably also don't need to lock your gem versions until you have a more developed and stable stack.  You might as well upgrade everything early on since some of the versions you have our out of date.  To upgrade your gems just remove all the version stuff after each gem line i.e.

```
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
```

can just be

```
gem 'coffee-rails'
```

After removing them all, then run

```
bundle update
```

Here is a [patchfile](https://gist.github.com/lacostenycoder/b610b3598283b7dd7b04b3530f5b94e6) which will do these things in case you have a problem. You can save this locally and then just run `git apply fix_gem_dependancies.patch` if you like.

UPDATE LAST ONE: This is the last thing I'm doing on this.  Get rid of gems you don't need, just use this Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.3'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'puma', '~> 3.7'
gem 'sass-rails'
gem 'uglifier'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder'
gem 'sdoc'

gem 'autoprefixer-rails'

gem 'execjs'

gem 'materialize-sass'


group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
  gem 'capybara', '~> 2.13'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
end

gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

The patch I sent you should have fixed the routes but you obviously don't know what you're doing with git.  So here is your routes.rb file

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root 'pages#home'

  get 'about' => 'pages#about'

  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

Comment: I installed the patch and it gives me this error (https://imgur.com/a/dhp0tSK), why?

Comment: "You should just use gem 'mini_racer' and get rid of therubyracer. Do that and run bundle install. You will also need to clean up merge conflict stuff left in your routes.rb file. Do that before bundle install and you should be good." How you do it?

Comment: The dependency mini_racer (>= 0) will be unused by any of the platforms Bundler is installing for. Why? @lacostenycoder

Comment: Now rails server does not work. Why? (https://imgur.com/a/b7UGCUE)
Can not you fix the files directly from GitHub?
Now this (https://imgur.com/a/6JQvTWl), why?

Comment: There is so much basic stuff you don't understand, you really need to take some courses to learn what you are trying to do.  Rails is not for beginners.  You need to set up your development environment and use a ruby version manager, I suggest using RVM  https://rvm.io/rvm/install  and you need to learn how to use git. https://www.git-tower.com/learn/

Comment: See how to fix merge conflicts https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=__cR7uPBOIk